# How to dissolve separated polygons into a large one?

Tags: r, qgis

I have a shape file that I can read like this in R:

```
    library(rgdal)
    shape <- readOGR(dsn = "~/path", layer = "a")
```

I am interested in the whole region that cover all polygons (black curve here). How to dissolve all polygons even those separated into one polygon like this?

I am open to solutions from R or Qgis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using R & the `sf` package you can make a convex hull of the unioned (if necessary) shapefile.  Since you haven't included data, I've used the `nc` data included with the `sf` package to illustrate the method.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# setting up sample data,
# you'll need to use st_read() to read your shapefile, not readOGR()
nc <-  st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source 
#>   `.../sf/shape/nc.shp' 
#>   using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27


nc <- nc[c(1:30, 85:81),] #Use some non-contiguous counties

# make a convex hull of the unioned geometries
nc_hull <- st_convex_hull(st_union(nc))

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = nc, fill = NA, color = 'red') +
  geom_sf(data = nc_hull, fill = NA, color = 'black')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Try `st_make_valid()` to get rid of the errors geometry errors.  `st_crop()` works for me.  Otherwise try `your_sf[st_within(your_sf, hull_sf, sparse = F),] `  Not much else I can do without some data to reproduce errors.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `ext= ...` line.

Comment: That is not how you would do it.  Maybe read through https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/index.html or post sample data.

Comment: fields are just columns & sf objects are just like data.frames.  select columns with `dplyr::select()` or bracketted subsetting `nc[,3]` (for the third column) or any other method of selecting columns of a df.